# Test memory leak in Java

Tags: java, testing, jmx

I have an application server which suffers from memory leak. This leak causes that `JSF` `ManagedBeans` aren't garbage collected from the memory after session expiration. We now have a fix and I would like to develop an automated regression test to make sure that we won't introduce this issue again in next releases.

So I am thinking about having the test in `Arquillian` which will deploy sample application to the server and access it, then wait for session expiration, perform garbage collection and check whether are beans in memory or not. So first two steps are not a problem - but

- how to perform garbage collection on the fly?`System.gc()` isn't guarantee anything, is it?
- and second, how to do memory lookup?I suppose it's possible somehow with `MBeans` and `JMX` but I have no experience with that

So my question is - is it even possible to achieve this in some automated fashion?And if yes, what would be your approach?

Comment: What implementation and version of JSF do you use?

Comment: I use more versions but I don't really see how it's relevant to my question (GC and JMX stuff)

Comment: But yes, this is not a problem from version 2.1.19 (but we have to support order versions and this problem can occur again, who knows:)

Comment: But the implementation is important. Do you use MyFaces or Mojarra? I ask, because I saw problem with memory weak at MyFaces implementation for version 2.1.x. I don't remember x for now